# ESLint ignore specific rule for a specific directory

Tags: eslint

Is it possible with ESLint to ignore one specific rule for an entire directory?

In my case, I would like to ignore `import/prefer-default-export` for a directory named `commonComponents`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable eslint rules for folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250257/disable-eslint-rules-for-folder)

Comment: @A-312 it does, but I think the answers are of better quality here.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

[ESLint configuration (`.eslintrc`) files](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#using-configuration-files) are hierarchical:

> ESLint will automatically look for them in the directory of the file to be linted, and in successive parent directories all the way up to the root directory of the filesystem. This option is useful when you want different configurations for different parts of a project or when you want others to be able to use ESLint directly without needing to remember to pass in the configuration file.

You can disable the `import/prefer-default-export` rule for the `commonComponents` directory by creating a `.eslintrc` file with the following content in that directory:

```js
{
    "rules": {
        "import/prefer-default-export": "off"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me where did you find the documentation for how to toggle this rule? The eslint-plugin-import docs were no help

Comment: @Dimitris Not sure what you mean. The rule has [no options](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/prefer-default-export.md), so it's just a simple on/off as per the [ESLint documentation](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50101673/ is better for this use case.

Answer (score 112):

You can also use the "overrides" key to declare rules for different glob patterns.

Have a read of [Configuration Based on Glob Patterns](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-based-on-glob-patterns)

> Sometimes a more fine-controlled configuration is necessary, for example if the configuration for files within the same directory has to be different. Therefore you can provide configurations under the overrides key that will only apply to files that match specific glob patterns, using the same format you would pass on the command line (e.g., app/**/*.test.js).

I use this to remove the `no-unused-expressions` rule from my test files like so;

```js
"overrides": [{
  "files": [ "*.spec.js" ],
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-expressions": 0
  }
}]
```

Comment: This is the best solution.  We shouldn't have to add a new file every time we want to ignore a rule for a folder like in the accepted answer.

Comment: This is a much better way than the accepted answer.

Comment: Best solution IMO, still in 2023

Answer (score 3):

If there are multiple directories that you want to apply your rules to, then you can create different configs for different purposes. For example:

- `.eslintrc.json` for common config
- `.eslintrc-main.json` for main linting and run `eslint -c .eslintrc-main src test`
- `.eslintrc-comp.json` for components and run `eslint -c .eslintrc-comp  commonComponents fooBarComponent`

Answer (score -2):

## YAML version :

```
rules:
  no-unused-expressions: true

overrides:
  - files: *-tests.js
    rules:
      no-unused-expressions: false
```