# Disable eslint rules for folder

Tags: eslint

Is there a way to disable specific rules for a folder? For example, I don't want to have required JSDoc comments for all my test files in the `test` folder. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: eslint-babel seems to ignore any .eslint-ignore files and settings.

Answer (score 480, accepted):

To ignore some folder from eslint rules we could create the file `.eslintignore` in root directory and add there the path to the folder we want omit (the same way as for `.gitignore`).

Here is the example from the ESLint docs on [Ignoring Files and Directories](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#ignoring-files-and-directories):

```
# path/to/project/root/.eslintignore
# /node_modules/* and /bower_components/* in the project root are ignored by default

# Ignore built files except build/index.js
build/*
!build/index.js
```

Comment: This solution doesn't really answer the original question, which asks how to disable *specific* rules for a particular directory. Here you're disabling *all* rules for the given directories. Better answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41316801/882638

Comment: Excerpt from the [ESLint documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#ignoring-files-and-directories)
"_In addition to any patterns in a .eslintignore file, ESLint always ignores files in /node_modules/* and /bower_components/*._"
So there's no need to add `/node_modules`, `/dist` alone is enough to exclude the both of the directories.
Also glob pattern is supported whilst specifying (sub)directories.

Comment: Is there the way to do it with vue.config.js or package.json?

Comment: Is there anyway of configuring which directories to ignore in the `.eslintrc.json` configuration file itself so we don't need yet another .estlint file and we can inherit ignore values from an `eslint-config-myconfig` shared configuration?

Comment: There are multiple similar posts on this. I needed: `--ignore-path` and/or `--ignore-pattern`, and I think that _also_ accurately answers this question.

Comment: Beware running `eslint src/**` because it somehow bypassed my `.eslinignore` file and caused an error because eslint was trying to apply its linter in subfolders where there was no files, and was crashing because of that. - Fixed it by running `eslint src/` instead

Comment: To answer my own comment from a year ago, as of ESLint 6.7.0+, you can now use a top-level attribute `ignorePatterns` to provide an Array of patterns to ignore. Read the release announcement here: https://eslint.org/blog/2019/11/eslint-v6.7.0-released

Answer (score 151):

The previous answers were in the right track, but the complete answer for this is going to be about [disabling rules only for a group of files](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#configuration-based-on-glob-patterns), there you'll find the documentation needed to disable/enable rules for certain folders (Because in some cases you don't want to ignore the whole thing, only disable certain rules). Example:

```json
    {
        "env": {},
        "extends": [],
        "parser": "",
        "plugins": [],
        "rules": {},
        "overrides": [
          {
            "files": ["test/*.spec.js"], // Or *.test.js
            "rules": {
              "require-jsdoc": "off"
            }
          }
        ],
        "settings": {}
    }
```

Comment: This answer is better because you can turn off a _specific_ rule for a given directory. Instead of just turning off all rules for a directory.

Comment: This initially didn’t work for me. Make sure you don’t have a `.eslintrc.js` in that folder with an `extends: "../.eslintrc.js"`!

Comment: In this method, is there any solution to turn off all eslint for the folder?

Comment: This is the actual answer I was looking for in my search.

Answer (score 65):

**In ESLint 6.7.0+ use "ignorePatterns": [].**

*Paths can begin with `/`, like `/dist/**` or `/test*/**`, but cannot begin with `./`, like `./build/**`.*

You can tell ESLint to ignore specific files and directories using ignorePatterns in your config files.

example of **.eslintrc.js**

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    // ...
  },
  extends: [
    // ...
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    // ...
  },
  plugins: [
    // ...
  ],
  rules: {
    // ...
  },
  ignorePatterns: ["src/test/*"], // <<< ignore all files in test folder
};
```

Or you can ignore files with some extension:

```
ignorePatterns: ['**/*.js']
```

You can read the user-guide doc here.

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/ignoring-code

Comment: And notice that don't start your path with `./src/foo/bar`. Use `src/foo/bar` instead.

Comment: @Kindred Importantly, you can start with `/`, and probably should for clarity, just not `./` which is a dumb oversight from the designers. `./` is expected.

Answer (score 3):

## YAML version :

```
overrides:
  - files: *-tests.js
    rules:
      no-param-reassign: 0
```

## Example of specific rules for mocha tests :

You can also set a specific env for a folder, like this :

```
overrides:
  - files: test/*-tests.js
    env:
      mocha: true
```

This configuration will fix error message about `describe` and `it` not defined, only for your test folder:

> /myproject/test/init-tests.js
> 6:1  **error**  'describe' is not defined  no-undef
> 9:3  **error**  'it' is not defined        no-undef

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, for some reason ignoring a path using `.eslintignore` may not work. If you are using a typescript project, the best practice is to exclude those paths in `tsconfig.json` like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "declaration.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/your-custom-path"
  ]
}
```

This will ensure that your build will be completed successfully.