# Is there a way to ignore test files for eslint-plugin-security?

Tags: node.js, eslint, eslintignore

With a node.js project, I've added eslint-plugin-security and it is giving a lot of warnings for code in my test/spec files (using mochajs).  Since the test code won't be running in production, these don't seem as useful as they do in the project's actual code.  (A lot of Generic Object Injection Sink warnings )

Is there a way to have the security plugin ignore certain files other than putting `/* eslint-disable */` at the top of every spec file?

Comment: So maybe a better question is "Is there a way to configure ignore rules per plugin?"

Comment: What I went with was using https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-cascading-and-hierarchy

project/.eslintrc.js  [has plugins that apply to everything: prettier]
project/src/.eslintrc.js [adds override to add eslint-plugin-security]
project/tests/.eslintrc.js [adds override to add eslint-plugin-mocha]
I'm not really in love with that setup though because of the way it spreads the eslint configs around, I'd rather have just one file.  

Also found, but did not use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-disable

Answer (score 24):

The best way I found to deal with this case is based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50101673/275780).
You can override parts of your eslint file in a subfolder. In my case I'm disabling problematic rules from a jest plugin inside my e2e tests folder. Example .eslintrc.js in /e2e-tests/ :

```
module.exports = {
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ["*.spec.js"],

      rules: {
        "jest/valid-expect": 0
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Just a little note for anyone reading this: If you're using an .eslintrc file, you'll need to wrap properties like in double quotes like `"overrides"`, `"files"` and `"rules"`, but ensure that the `0` is not quoted.

Comment: This is fucking awesome!  Thank you 

Answer (score 20):

There is three way to ignore files or folders:

#### 1. Creating a `.eslintignore` on your project root folder with the thing you want to ignore:

`**/*.js`

#### 2. Using eslint cli & the `--ignore-path` to specify another file where your ignore rules will be located

```
eslint --ignore-path .jshintignore file.js
```

#### 3. Using your package.json

```
{
  "name": "mypackage",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "eslintConfig": {
      "env": {
          "browser": true,
          "node": true
      }
  },
  "eslintIgnore": ["*.spec.ts", "world.js"]
}
```

[Official Documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#ignoring-files-and-directories)

On my side, I had issue with Intellij IDEA where eslint was checking files in a folder only dedicated to Typescript (+tslint) which was a pain, so I've picked solution 3.

Comment: Thanks for the tips but I am still getting the red line in my test/*.js files

Comment: hey Scott, you should either consider asking a new question or giving more infos on your setup. Saying "this doesn't work" does not help anybody figuring it out.

Comment: Hi @Hugo, I just open up settings.json and add the property: "eslint.enable": false

Comment: this is not my solution, I'm only talking about ignoring specific files.

Comment: yeah, I know but your solutions doesn't in my environment. Is there any other options?

Comment: try to reproduce the issue in another environement, there is probably something wrong with yours, or something outdated.