# "to" is not a valid property of expect jest/valid-expect

Tags: javascript, eslint, cypress

I'm trying to fix `eslint` warnings in my code and I get a lot of these. The problem is that the files in question are not jest tests but `cypress` tests. The tests are valid because `cypress` `expect` is not the same as `jest` `expect`.
Is there a way to either ignore the `cypress` directory for `jest/valid-expect` warnings ? or if that fails just ignore the directory for any `jest` validation ? There's no `jest` tests in that directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250257/disable-eslint-rules-for-folder

Comment: more of a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41316551/eslint-ignore-specific-rule-for-a-specific-directory

Comment: None of these links really solve the problem tho. We should be able to specify to use the correct `expect`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50101673/275780) provides most of the information needed (thanks CRayen for pointing me to another question (which was a duplicate of another)).

Basically you can put a .eslintrc file into any subfolder in which you want to override rules. Then you need to add a section like the one in the answer:

```
"overrides": [{
  "files": [ "*.spec.js" ],
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-expressions": 0
  }
}]
```

where you explicitly turn off the rules you don't want to be used to check the files listed by setting them to 0.

Comment: This hides the error, but it's not a good answer. Not sure why you would get even 8 votes. We should be able to still have eslint and differentiate the different `expect`

Answer (score 0):

Add to the first line in the file:

`/* eslint-disable jest/valid-expect */`